# Codeigniter submitting form1 form2 on form_open

Tags: codeigniter

any idea how to handle this problem ? my problem is when i submit on form2  the form1 automatic submit to. I want is when i submit on form2 only the form2 submit it. Please check this sample code.

```
<?php echo form_open('form1'); ?>

<input type="text" name="name">


                <?php echo form_open('form2'); ?>
                    <input type="text" name="note">
                        <input type="submit" value="button2"> // this form2 is to insert note on this day
                <?php echo form_close(); ?>

              // then under this form2 we have a table. Table for list of note that all ready insert.          


 <input type="submit" value="button1">  // this form1 is to save all. the "Name" and also the note that we insert it on form2              
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Why are you placing your form2 inside form1?

Comment: because under the form2 i have a table . and that table is saving under the form1. thats why i need two form. this question is possible sir ?

Comment: the form2 is saving under the table.

Comment: It is not good idea to nest form elements. There are some alternatives to make it work. But I guess most of the time you will not need it. can you post your complete code and we can review it.

Comment: wait i edit the sample code

Comment: Is not possible to handle your notes with form1?

Comment: No sir. a have to insert all under the form1

Comment: sir i have a idea but i don`t know how to implement the form action on javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is a good way of programming to nest the forms.But after doing bit research for your question found this link which can come to your help.[Click here](http://markuzweb.blogspot.in/2009/10/embedding-html-forms-within-another.html)

Hope that will work for you.All the best!

Comment: i have some one problem but is not a big problem sir .

Answer (score 0):

Change your nested submit element to

```
<input type="submit" name="form2_button" value="form2_submit"/>
```

Then, you can check the inner form submission using

```
if(isset($_POST["form2_button"]))` or in codeigniter you can input->post('form2_button')
```

Having a form nested under another form is not a valid HTML/XHTML. But you can try the follow code above.